# How to pass a function as a parameter in c++?

Tags: c++, function, templates, parameters

I have this file
Matrix.h:

```
#ifndef MTM_MATRIX_H_
#define MTM_MATRIX_H_
#include <assert.h>


namespace mtm
{
 
 template<class T>
 
    class Matrix
 {
     T** data;
     int col;
     int row;
    public:
          Matrix(int row,int col, T intial=0);
          T& operator()(int row, int col);
          const T& operator() (int row, int col) const;
          //some functions
        template<typename Function>
        Matrix<T> apply(Function function);

};
//ctor
template<class T>
 Matrix<T>::Matrix(int row,int col, T intial):data(new T*[row]), col(col), row(row)
        {
            
            for (int i = 0; i < row; i++)
                {
                     data[i] = new T[col];
                }
             for(int i=0;i<row;i++)
            {
                for(int j=0;j<col;j++)
                {
                    data[i][j]=intial;
                }
            }
         }
template<class T>
T& Matrix<T>::operator()(int row, int col)
{
    return this->data[row][col];
}
template<class T>
const T& Matrix<T>::operator() (int row, int col) const
{
    return this->data[row][col];
}
template<class T>
template<typename Function>
Matrix<T> Matrix<T>::apply(Function function) 
{
    Matrix<T> new_mat(this->row,this->col);
    for(int i=0;i<new_mat.row;i++)
    {
        for(int j=0;j<new_mat.col; j++)
        {
            new_mat(i,j)= function(this->data[i][j]);
        }
    }
    return new_mat;
}
}
  
#endif
```

I edited the code and now I have a different error about the same function `apply(Function function)`

---

ps: if there are any more informaion needed about my class, please tell me in the comments, and don't just close my question, without asking me to edit it first..

errors:

```
test_partB.cpp: In function ‘int main()’:
test_partB.cpp:54:58: error: no matching function for call to ‘mtm::Matrix<int>::apply(Square) const’
         const mtm::Matrix<int> mat_2=mat_1.apply(Square());
                                                          ^
test_partB.cpp:54:58: note: candidate is:
In file included from test_partB.cpp:3:0:
Matrix.h:593:11: note: mtm::Matrix<T> mtm::Matrix<T>::apply(Function) [with Function = Square; T = int] <near match>
 Matrix<T> Matrix<T>::apply(Function function)
           ^
Matrix.h:593:11: note:   no known conversion for implicit ‘this’ parameter from ‘const mtm::Matrix<int>*’ to ‘mtm::Matrix<int>*’
```

code that used the function:

```
//this is **
const mtm::Matrix<int> mat_1(1,2,4);
        const mtm::Matrix<int> mat_2=mat_1.apply(Square());
```

the thing is I must not change **

```
class Square { 
    public: 
        int operator()(int val){ 
          return val*val; 
    } 
};
```

Comment: What's needed are the endless errors, and an example of how you tried to use that code because that should work fine.

Comment: Please provider a [mcve]. How are you calling this?

Comment: Assuming the call is this, `const mtm::Matrix<int> mat_2=mat_1.apply(Square());` then `Square()` looks very much like a function call, not a function. But obviously there's still plenty of code missing.

Comment: [std::function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function).

Comment: `apply` is not marked `const` so it cannot be called on a `const` matrix.

Comment: So one error is that `template<typename Function> Matrix<T> apply(Function function);` should be `template<typename Function> Matrix<T> apply(Function function) const;`

Comment: @john I tried it now and it gave me this error :  ``` error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘class mtm::Matrix<T>’
 Matrix<T> Matrix<T>::apply(Function function) const```

Comment: Post the `//some code` and the definition of `apply`

Comment: Where is the closing `}` of the `namespace mtm`? Or the function definition of `apply`? Please create a proper [mcve], this is still missing details

Comment: @raghad There's too much missing to diagnose the problem, try to create a complete example that is short enough to post here. The missing closing `}` pointed out by unholy sheep is a red flag though.

Comment: I added some code, is there anything else I should add?

Comment: Did you mess up your copy-paste? Now you have a templated namespace (?) and an `IntMatrix` class, and no longer have a `Matrix` template class defined anywhere.

Comment: yes thank you i did

Comment: @kevin edited ..

Comment: You still have a nonsense templated namespace. Please copy-paste the *exact* code that you're compiling.

Comment: @Kevin it should be fine now

Comment: this is the code I am compiling

Comment: This has nothing to do with passing functions as parameters. Swap `template<class T>` and `template<typename Function>` in the definition of `apply`. (This is not the only problem with this code as posted)

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. yes after swapping them I didn't get the error, but I got another error, so I am going to edit my question

Comment: All the other problems are unrelated to the titular question as well. `this.row,this.col` is invalid, `new_mat(i,j)` is invalid, `this(i,j)` is out of this world, and `function()(x)` is not how you usually call a function named `functtion`.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.  `new_mat(i,j) ` is valid because of the overloaded  `operator()(int row, int col)` but you are defiantly  right about everything else

Comment: thank you so much guys , the problem is solved

Comment: @raghad Please answer your own question on how the problem was solved, for the ease of future visitor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the solution was to declare the function in the class like this

```
 template<typename Function>
        Matrix<T> apply(Function function);
```

and then write it's body and use it this way:

```
template<class T>
template<typename Function>
Matrix<T> Matrix<T>::apply(Function function) 
{
  int k=3;
  int n=function(k);
}
```